# How to change the background of a form using a button and an image from the resources file in C#

Tags: c#, button

So I need to figure out how to change the background image of the form using a button on the form. I've done it before but I can't figure it out anymore..
What it's supposed to do is use an image from the resources folder then change the background of that form to that image. If anyone can help me out that'd be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Your_Resource_Image_Name;
}
```